# Why is EIP-712 necessary for readable transaction signing (MetaMask)?

Tags: metamask, meta-transactions, eip712

I am implementing the EIP-712 for metatransactions and I was wondering, why is it necessary to implement such protocol in order to have a transparent signing method for the user?

Since MetaMask has access to the smart contract and knows well the function we're going to call, couldn't it extrapolate the parameters names and values from the data and show them to the user in a readable format? It doesn't allow for custom names to appear, but usually those match the ones from the contract function signature.